# showing random value in div element with javascript

Tags: javascript

I want my div element to work like a timer and shows random numbers with an interval of 1s. http://jsfiddle.net/NHAvS/46/. That is my code:

```
var arrData = [];
for (i=0;i<1000;i++)
{
      arrData.push({"bandwidth":Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)});
}

var div = document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML =arrData;
document.getElementById('wrapper').style.left = '200px';
document.getElementById('wrapper').style.top = '100px';
```

but the problem is that it only shows 1 data at a time. any idea how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Put it in a function and call it every second using `setInterval()`.

Comment: I wanted to expand on the other replies: Your web browser tab is essentially single threaded to the developer.  That is, page rendering and execution of scripts run serially, one after the other.  For that reason, the SetInterval/SetTimeOut functions (google them for the proper casing) exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're better off using jQuery and CSS to achieve your desired result.  jQuery to find the element and to display the random number; and CSS instead of manually setting the position.  (Obviously jQuery is just a personal choice and `document.getElementById` will suffice - but if you're planning on manipulating the DOM a lot, jQuery is probably a better route to take).  See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NHAvS/53/)

```
$(function () {
    var arrData = [];
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        arrData.push({
            "bandwidth": Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
        });
    }

    var index = 0;

    setInterval(function(){
        $("#wrapper").text(arrData[index].bandwidth);
        index++;
    }, 1000);    
});
```

Comment: Thanks, and what if I want to show it on a specific place in the page, I have added this: document.getElementById('wrapper').style.left = '50px'; document.getElementById('wrapper').style.top= '100px'; but it does not work –

Comment: Easily done using jQuery and absolute positioning: [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NHAvS/54/)

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
setInterval(myfun,1000);

var div = document.getElementById('wrapper');
function myfun(){
   div.innerHTML ='bandwidth :'+Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
}
```

Take a Look: http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/NHAvS/49/

Note: your example was messed up as on left side it was set to load in head which means your div would be undefined every time your script loads before your dom. so setting it to onload make it works little more. :D

Note: also you seem to be chaining functions as in jquery, but in javascript you don't do that. The functions are made to do that. i.e. `div= ..getElementById..innerHtml='balbla';` would set div = bla... not element.

Comment: Thanks, and what if I want to show it on a specific place in the page, I have added this: document.getElementById('wrapper').style.left = '50px'; 
document.getElementById('wrapper').style.top= '100px'; but it does not work

Comment: 1st choose the answer when it has answered your question. And do you want position to be random too. If not then you should specify position in css. Which can be done easily but you need to answer this. Do you want it to be fixed in reference to page or browser.

Comment: `document.getElementById('wrapper').style.position= 'relative';` put this before you write the code you told me in comments.OK

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
var delay = 1000, // 1000 ms = 1 sec
    i;
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML = arrData[i];
  i++;
}, delay);
```

Comment: Don't you have to iterate through the array as well?

Comment: Yeah right, fixed. Of course this is not meant as a silver bullet answer... it's just an example